# Ionic tab event to details

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but I can't seem to get it to work.

I did a "starter tabs" and have this as a few tabs:

```
.state('tab.events', {
  url: '/events',
  views: {
    'tab-events': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/tab-events.html',
      controller: 'EventsCtrl'
    }
  }
})
.state('tab.event', {
  url: '/events/:eventId',
  views: {
    'tab-event': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/tab-event.html',
      controller: 'EventCtrl'
    }
  }
})
```

And in my tab-events.html I have:

```
<ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-repeat="event in events" href="#/events/{{event.id}}">
```

Whenever I click on a event, the URL changes by adding the ID number but the oage remains on tab-events.html and doesn't show the detail thats in tab-event.html. What am I missing or doing wrong?

**UPDATE

The error in my console is:

```
Error: Could not resolve '#/tab/events/1' from state 'tab.events'
    at Object.transitionTo (ionic.bundle.js:49045)
   at Object.go (ionic.bundle.js:48978)
   at ionic.bundle.js:50028
     at ionic.bundle.js:30889
    at completeOutstandingRequest (ionic.bundle.js:18574)
     at ionic.bundle.js:18846
```

Comment: Please, share a plunker so we can see where the error is.

Comment: The error in console says:

Error: Could not resolve '#/tab/events/1' from state 'tab.events'
    at Object.transitionTo (ionic.bundle.js:49045)
    at Object.go (ionic.bundle.js:48978)
    at ionic.bundle.js:50028
    at ionic.bundle.js:30889
    at completeOutstandingRequest (ionic.bundle.js:18574)
    at ionic.bundle.js:18846